# Iphone SDK streaming the movies

Tags: iphone, ios4

i want to stream/play some movies with iphone. I have implemented the MPMoviePlayerViewController like that:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController* theMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL]; 
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMoviePlayer];
```

But the streaming/playing is too slow. I have a normal server, also it doesn't provide streaming options.

My question is : Must i have a stream-server or should i have configure something on my code?

Thanks,
best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to determine whether the problem is with server or not, try to play some local video file on your host.

Comment: I can play the videos with IE or Chrome. I have no problem to play the videos on my Laptop-Browser. But the streaming is very slow at iphone(at Safari too).

Comment: And what about playing local video files? Not streams.

Comment: I can play the local video files too without any problem. (All my videos are converted to MP4-format.)

Comment: Ok, then try this approach, cause it seems to be problems with the player: download the video data manually and write it to the local file. Then play video, that would be loaded from that file, and not the stream.

Comment: You don't have to download the whole file before playback. Just determine what is the sufficient size for the buffer.

Comment: I want to play the movies from a server. I'm programming an application, that has more movies with size > 50MB. So it's bad idea for my application to download the files to the iphone and then play it.

Comment: Read the comment above:  you don't have to download the whole file and then play it.

Comment: It is enough to preload some amount of data, and then just append the file. That's all.